# How to add HTML dependencies like images and css with HtmlSpanner?

Tags: java, android, html, image, fromhtml

I have the source code of index.html, the css file, the images, etc. But I do not know how to "add" the dependencies of index.html in Htmlspanner to allow them to be included in the final rendering, using the Android library HtmlSpanner

`CharSequence cs = htmlspanner.fromHtml(String.valueOf(index))`

I tried with ImageHandler, but I do not know how to fix it
can anyone help me?

Comment: what are you trying to do ? purpose please

Comment: epub reader, i need view image and style